# Como agregar filas a una tabla desde otra tabla con buscador

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

estoy haciendo un sistema sencillo para mi negocio todo va bien hasta ahorita que me atore, espero puedan ayudarme se los agradecería bastante, les explico primero un poco de mi código y su función.

Tengo este input que busca los productos en mi base de datos y los muestra en una tabla.

ventasgen.php

```
   <center>
      Buscar producto por: <B>NOMBRE</B> o <B>CODIGO</B> <br><br>
      <input type="text" id="bus" name="bus" onkeyup="loadXMLDoc()" required autofocus/>
      <br><br>
      <div id="myDiv"></div>
   </center>


<br><br>
<div class="row-fluid sortable">        
    <div class="box span12">
        <div class="box-header" data-original-title>
            <h2><i class="icon-usd"></i><span class="break"></span>PRODUCTOS AGREGADOS</h2>
            <!--<div class="box-icon">
                <a href="add_new_compra.php"><i class="halflings-icon white plus"></i>
                    <h7 style="color: white;"" >XXXXX</h7>
                </a>
            </div>-->
        </div>
        <div class="box-content">
            <table border="1">
              <thead>
                  <tr>
                      <th>ID</th>
                      <th>Nombre Producto</th>
                      <th>Unidad Producto</th>
                      <th>Stock</th>
                  </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Aqui aparezca el id del producto</td>
                        <td>Aqui aparezca el nombre del producto</td>
                        <td>Aqui aparezca la unidad del producto</td>
                        <td>Aqui aparezca el stock</b></center></td>
                    </tr>
              </tbody>
          </table>            
        </div>
    </div><!--/span-->

</div><!--/row-->
```

mi archivo ajax_concuerdan.js

```
function loadXMLDoc()
{
var xmlhttp;

var n=document.getElementById('bus').value;

if(n==''){
document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML="";
return;
}

if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else
{// code for IE6, IE5
xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
{
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
{
document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
}
}
xmlhttp.open("POST","ventasgenBUSCAR.php",true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xmlhttp.send("q="+n);
}
```

y mi archivo ventasgenBUSCAR.php

```
<?php
  @session_start();
  error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_DEPRECATED);
  include("includes/connection1.php");
  $q=$_POST['q'];

  $res=mysqli_query($conn,"select * from `tblproducts` 
    where nombre_producto LIKE '".$q."%'
    OR id_producto LIKE '".$q."%'
    OR CONCAT(nombre_producto,' ',unidad_producto) LIKE '".$q."%'
    ");


  if(mysqli_num_rows($res)==0){

    echo '<b>¡ NO EXISTEN PRODUCTOS CON ESA BUSQUEDA !</b>';
  ?>
  <!DOCTYPE HTML>
  <CENTER>
    <br>
    AGREGA EL PRODUCTO EN LA SECCION DE PRODUCTOS</a>
  </CENTER>


  <?php
  }else{
    echo '<b>Seleccionar producto:</b><br><br>';
  ?>

  <!DOCTYPE HTML>

  <table border="1px">
   <tr>
    <th>PRODUCTO </th>
    <th>PRESENTACION</th>
    <th></th>
   </tr>
   <?php  while($fila=mysqli_fetch_array($res)){?>
   <tr>
    <td><?php echo $fila['nombre_producto']; ?> </td>
    <td align="center"><?php echo $fila['unidad_producto']; ?></td>
    <td><img src="img/add.png" width="20px" height="20px">
   </tr>
   <?php }?>
  </table>
  </html>

  <?php } ?>
```

todo esto me genera una pagina que al escribir el nombre del producto aparece una tabla con los productos iguales o similares ue hay, como la imagen que adjunto...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**

> mi duda es como puedo hacer que al dar click en el signo de mas verde
>   de cada producto que tengo en la tabla se agregen en la tabla de abajo
>   ....

**

Muchas gracias por su tiempo y respuesta saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Tu código PHP tiene serios problemas de seguridad. Si alguien busca el producto `coca-cola';drop table tblproducts;--` ya te imaginarás lo que pasa.

Respondiendo sólo al comportamiento javascript:

Necesitas poner en tus resultados de búsqueda la misma info que necesitas para llenar la tabla de abajo. Por ejemplo, añadir el campo "stock" y el campo "id". El primero como columna de la tabla y el segundo, si prefieres, como atributo ID de la fila en la tabla superior:

```js
function add(element) {
var fila = element.parentNode.parentNode,
    id=fila.id,
    nombre = fila.querySelector('.nombre').cloneNode(true),
    cantidad = fila.querySelector('.cantidad').cloneNode(true),
    stock = fila.querySelector('.stock').cloneNode(true),
    id_producto=document.createElement('td'),
    nueva_fila=document.createElement('tr');
    
    id_producto.textContent = id;
    id_producto.className='id';
    
    nueva_fila.appendChild(id_producto);
    nueva_fila.appendChild(nombre);
    nueva_fila.appendChild(cantidad);
    nueva_fila.appendChild(stock);
    
    var carrito =document.getElementById('carrito');
    carrito.querySelector('tbody').appendChild(nueva_fila);
    
    
}
```

```css
table {
border:1px solid;
}
 td {
border: 1px solid;
padding: 3px;
}
 th {
font-weight: bold;
border: 1px solid;
padding: 3px;
}
```

```html
Productos que coinciden:

<table id="busqueda">
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th class="nombre">Nombre Producto</th>
    <th class="cantidad">Cantidad Producto</th>
    <th class="stock">Stock Producto</th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr id="1">
    <td class="nombre">Nombre 1</td>
    <td class="cantidad">Cantidad 1</td>
    <td class="stock">Stock 1</td>
    <td>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="add(this)">
      <img src="https://cache.addthiscdn.com/icons/v2/thumbs/32x32/addthis.png"/>
     </a>
   </td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="2">
    <td class="nombre">Nombre 2</td>
    <td class="cantidad">Cantidad 2</td>
    <td class="stock">Stock 2</td>
    <td>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="add(this)">
      <img src="https://cache.addthiscdn.com/icons/v2/thumbs/32x32/addthis.png"/>
     </a>
   </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>

<p>Su carrito de compras</p>

<table id="carrito">
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th class="id">ID Producto</th>
    <th class="nombre">Nombre Producto</th>
    <th class="cantidad">Cantidad Producto</th>
    <th class="stock">Stock Producto</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Hay maneras más cortas de hacerlo pero encontré que este camino era el más didáctico para mostrarte qué ocurre tras bambalinas.

Comment: Upss soy nuevo en esto de php no sabia que se podia poner eso en el input buscare como darle seguridad a eso por otra parte deja revisar y acomodar el codigo y comento los resultados muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

Colocando el codigo que me muestras en el archivo ventasgenBUSCAR, de la siguiente manera, ya colocando los datos que necesito de otra tabla.

```
      <?php
  @session_start();
  error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_DEPRECATED);
  include("includes/connection.php");
  $q=$_POST['q'];


    $sql = "SELECT * FROM tblproducts INNER JOIN tblinventory
                      WHERE tblproducts.id_producto=tblinventory.id_producto
                      AND nombre_producto LIKE '".$q."%'";
    $res=mysql_query($sql);

  ?>
  <!DOCTYPE HTML>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function add(element) {
      var fila = element.parentNode.parentNode,
      id=fila.id,
      nombre_producto = fila.querySelector('.nombre_producto').cloneNode(true),
      unidad_producto = fila.querySelector('.unidad_producto').cloneNode(true),
      stock = fila.querySelector('.stock').cloneNode(true),
      id_producto=document.createElement('td'),
      nueva_fila=document.createElement('tr');

      id_producto.textContent = id;
      id_producto.className='id';

      nueva_fila.appendChild(id_producto);
      nueva_fila.appendChild(nombre_producto);
      nueva_fila.appendChild(unidad_producto);
      nueva_fila.appendChild(stock);

      var carrito =document.getElementById('carrito');
      carrito.querySelector('tbody').appendChild(nueva_fila);
  }
  </script>
  </head>


  <?php
  if(mysql_num_rows($res)==0){

    echo '<b>¡ NO EXISTEN PRODUCTOS CON ESA BUSQUEDA !</b>';
  ?>
  <!DOCTYPE HTML>
  <CENTER>
    <br>
    AGREGA EL PRODUCTO EN LA SECCION DE PRODUCTOS</a>
  </CENTER>


  <?php
  }else{
    echo '<b>Seleccionar producto:</b><br><br>';
  ?>

  <!DOCTYPE HTML>

  <table border="1px" id="busqueda">
   <tr>
    <th>ID PRODUCTO </th>
    <th>PRODUCTO </th>
    <th>PRESENTACION</th>
    <th>STOCK</th>
    <th></th>
   </tr>
   <?php  while($fila=mysql_fetch_array($res)){?>
   <tr>
    <td class="id_producto"><?php echo $fila['id_producto']; ?> </td>
    <td class="nombre_producto"><?php echo $fila['nombre_producto']; ?> </td>
    <td align="center" class="unidad_producto"><?php echo $fila['unidad_producto']; ?></td>
    <td align="center" class="stock"><?php echo $fila['stock']; ?></td>
    <td><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="add(this)"><img src="img/add.png" width="20px" height="20px"></a></td>
   </tr>
   <?php }?>
  </table>

  <p>Su carrito de compras</p>

  <table id="carrito">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="id_producto">ID Producto</th>
      <th class="nombre_producto">Nombre Producto</th>
      <th class="unidad_producto">Cantidad Producto</th>
      <th class="stock">Stock Producto</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
  </table>


  </html>

  <?php } ?>
```

al dar click en agregar no muestra nada ni hace nada nose en que estoy mal, otra duda esto supongamos que funciona correctamente si necesito hacer la busqueda de otro producto se quitarian los productos que ya tengo agregados?

Saludos muchas gracias, 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]